# How to add a jpeg image from some source file in a dynamically generated image in php

Tags: php

Below is the code to generate an image dynamically in php. I want to add some image in  this dynamically created image. I've already tried my luck with imagecopy but failed because I think it deals with the already created image to copy one onto another.

```
<?php

$my_img = imagecreate( 1200, 630 );

$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 2,144,162 );

$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );

$text_colour1 = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 255 );

$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );

$font='C:\Windows\Fonts\ARLRDBD.ttf';

imagettftext($my_img, 48, 0,  450, 100, $text_colour, $font,"Hello World");

$font1='C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf';

imagettftext($my_img, 32, 0,  650, 160, $text_colour1, $font1,Hello World" );

imagettftext($my_img, 32, 0,  500, 300, $text_colour1, $font1,"Hello World" );

imagettftext($my_img, 32, 0,  560, 440, $text_colour1, $font1,"Hello World" );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );

imagepng( $my_img );

imagepng( $my_img,'Ethers.png' );

imagecolordeallocate( $text_colour );

imagecolordeallocate( $text_colour1 );

imagecolordeallocate( $background );

imagedestroy($my_img);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagedestroy($my_img);

?>
```

Comment: You also have image edit functions such as http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are readymade code available for playing with image edits.

Find the class from the following link.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6323-PHP-Manipulate-GIF-JPEG-and-PNG-images.html

This class can be used to manipulate GIF, JPEG and PNG images.

It can load an image in GIF, JPEG and PNG formats and perform several types of operations.

Currently it can resize the image, render a text on the image, render a watermark image and apply several types of effects like blur, edge detection, sharpen, emboss, etc..

The resulting image can be saved to a file or displayed as the current script output also in GIF, PNG and JPEG formats.

Comment: I am also aware of the library of image edit functions,but don't know which of them will work for me.

Comment: You can use Image merge http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php . The Class i suggested has the watermark. Watermark is nothing but adding an image with some opacity so that it looks like a water mark. If u have zero opacity, the image will show as it is and get merged.

Comment: Good.. Mark the answer as right so that it will be useful for people who search for similar questions :)